# Загрузка файла на сервер методом POST

Tags: php, c#, httpclient

Не получается загрузить файл на сайт через POST, пробовал разные примеры, но ни один не работает.

Код моей программы:
Первый вариант

```
WebRequest send = WebRequest.Create(@"http://site.ru/upload");
        send.Method = "POST";
        send.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=85645486461";
        send.ContentLength = 28163;    


        StringBuilder sendData = new StringBuilder();
        using (FileStream img = new FileStream("C:\\OpenServer\\1.jpg", FileMode.Open))
        {
            sendData.Append("filename=" + img.ToString());
        }

        byte[] byteData = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(sendData.ToString());
        send.ContentLength = byteData.Length;
        using (Stream sendStream = send.GetRequestStream())
        {
            sendStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
        }

        using (WebResponse result = send.GetResponse())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(result.GetResponseStream());
            //XDocument res = XDocument.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
            //res.Save("res.xml");               
        }
```

Второй вариант

```
public static string XmlHttpRequest(string urlString, string xmlContent)
    {
        string response = null;
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = null;//Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebRequest class.
        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = null;//Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebResponse class

        //Creates an HttpWebRequest for the specified URL.
        httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlString);

        try
        {
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlContent);
            //Set HttpWebRequest properties
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=85645486461";

            using (Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                //Writes a sequence of bytes to the current stream 
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                requestStream.Close();//Close stream
            }

            //Sends the HttpWebRequest, and waits for a response.
            httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            if (httpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //Get response stream into StreamReader
                using (Stream responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            httpWebResponse.Close();//Close HttpWebResponse
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {   //TODO: Add custom exception handling
            throw new Exception(we.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception(ex.Message); }
        finally
        {
            httpWebResponse.Close();
            //Release objects
            httpWebResponse = null;
            httpWebRequest = null;
        }
        return response;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        XmlHttpRequest("http://site.ru/upload", "C:\\OpenServer\\1.jpg");
    }
```

Comment: Можно использовать HTTPClient и MultipartFormDataContent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319886/http-multipartformdatacontent

Comment: Вот примеры правда на 1С с использованием классов .Net внизу пример разных контентов http://infostart.ru/public/466052/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел отличное [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)

```
public static  void UploadFilesToRemoteUrl(string url, string[] files,string
logpath, NameValueCollection nvc)
{

long length = 0;
string boundary = "----------------------------" +
DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");


HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpWebRequest2.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" +
boundary;
httpWebRequest2.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest2.KeepAlive = true;
httpWebRequest2.Credentials =
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;



Stream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" +
boundary + "\r\n");


string formdataTemplate = "\r\n--" + boundary +
"\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\";\r\n\r\n{1}";

foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
{
    string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]);
    byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
    memStream.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
}


memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";

for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{

    //string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "file" + i, files[i]);
    string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "uplTheFile", files[i]);

    byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);

    memStream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);


    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(files[i], FileMode.Open,
    FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    int bytesRead = 0;

    while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

    }


    memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);


    fileStream.Close();
}

httpWebRequest2.ContentLength = memStream.Length;

Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest2.GetRequestStream();

memStream.Position = 0;
byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
memStream.Close();
requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
requestStream.Close();


WebResponse webResponse2 = httpWebRequest2.GetResponse();

Stream stream2 = webResponse2.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);


MessageBox.Show(reader2.ReadToEnd());

webResponse2.Close();
httpWebRequest2 = null;
webResponse2 = null;
}
```

Использовал таки образом:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
HttpUploadFile("http://site.ru/upload", @"C:\\OpenServer\\1.jpg", "upload", "image/jpeg", nvc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот это

```
// Получаем путь к файл
var filePath = jQuery('#fileID').prop("files")[0];

// Создаем FormData объект
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', filePath );

//Можно отправить еще кое что если необходимо
formData.append('value', 'key' );

// Отпровляем файл
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'здесь адрес на который загружашь файл', // Вставь ссылку
    data: formData,
    dataType: "JSON", // Ожидаеться ответ в виде JSON
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function( data ) {
        console.log( 'Success' );
    },

    error: function( data ) {
        console.log( 'ERROR: output error data' );
        console.log( data );
    }
});
```

Comment: Программа написана на с#, а js на сайте обрабатывает закачку файла, пример нужен на шарпе